# Force horizontal orientation for custom camera overlay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to force orientation on my custom camera overlay, but I am struggling to get it to work, I have tried this,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```

but that does not seem to work anymore since Xcode updated to version 4.5.

Also, what would be the right way to force horizontal orientation on a single view, as I understand it the above is not best practice?

Answer (score 0):

For ios6, need to do the following things.

> - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
>     {
>          return YES;
>     }
>
> -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
>   {
>     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
>   }